# Why does "bundle exec" eat the parameters I pass in?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, exec, bundle, bundler

When I invoke commands using `bundle exec` it takes the parameters I pass in. An example for this would be:

```
bundle exec my_command run --verbose
```

In this case `--verbose` is used as a bundler argument where as it should be used for `my_command`. I know the following way would work:

```
bundle exec 'my_command run --verbose'
```

Is it possible to avoid the quotes? The command I use has already a lot of quotes. I expected something like this would work but it didn't:

```
bundle exec -- my_command run --verbose
```

I don't see much documentation about this for bundler. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have this problem, what version of bundler are you using?

Comment: I'm using bundler version 1.3.5

Answer (score 13):

This looks like what is a common problem when passing one command to another in the shell, and it looks like you're close to what I'd use. Instead of using:

```
bundle exec my_command run --verbose
```

Or:

```
bundle exec -- my_command run --verbose
```

Try:

```
bundle exec my_command -- run --verbose
```

Using `bundle exec --` breaks the command-chain for `bundle exec`. `exec` is a sub-command for `bundle` and `my_command` is a parameter for `exec`. The parameters for `my_command`, well, neither `bundle` or `exec` needs to know about them so the `--` goes where you want to break that chain of parameters to `bundle`.

Comment: For example, to run a specific ActiveSupport::TestCase `bundle exec ruby -- test/unit/class_test.rb -n '/test_a_method/'`

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting from [*source of bundler*](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L502), it is default behavior to pass all the parameters after `bundle exec` to `Kernel.exec`, so the `--verbose` parameters will be passed to your command, not `bundle`.

```
bundle exec my_command run --verbose
```

will run the following under the context of bundle

```
Kernel.exec('my_command', 'run', '--verbose')
```

and

```
bundle exec -- my_command run --verbose
```

results in an error because no command/script is named `--`.

Check the test case here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# coding: utf-8
# file: test.rb

p ARGV
```

test:

```
$ bundle exec ruby test.rb --verbose --arg1
["--verbose", "--arg1"]
```